# Issues with extract by mask tool

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1, clip, masking

I am using the extract by mask tool to fit my raster to a mask (province of Nova Scotia). I've noticed that the raster doesn't quite fit the mask; the north and south boundaries of the province is cut-off. Is there a way I can extend the boundaries of the raster to fit the mask? Below is a picture of the problem:

[image]

Comment: set your extent environment to the extent of the original data or the clipping shape... that will ensure the raster is a particular size, the pixels might be NoData but they will be there.

Comment: I just gave that a try and it didn't work - any other suggestions?

Comment: Are you saying the source raster doesn't go all the way to the intended extent? Try Euclidean Allocation http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//009z0000001m000000 to copy the closest raster value.. but **don't trust the data that is interpolated** it's only there for display.

Comment: Something of a guess here, but it appears your interpolated raster isn't as large as your mask area. Did *you* create that interpolation, or is it from another source? If you did it, you need to go back to *that* step and set the processing extent to match your mask layer rather than the extents of the sample points. If you didn't create the interpolation, then there isn't really an issue - there's nothing there to extract. Your only choice is to 'fake it'/reinterpolate in some way, such as Michael's suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

Per Chris W's comment suggestion I recreated my interpolated raster and used the mask to set the processing extents during interpolation rather than just the extents of the sample points. This resulted in an interpolation raster that fully covered the mask I want to use for extraction.